# Declares values on objects and output the values

Tags: php, oop, object, properties, methods

I need some guide or reference on how should I do this.
What I should do is, have a class structure named Cat and have a static method that outputs new object.

```
class Cat{
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $string;

    static public function ToData($Cat) {
        $input = "";
        foreach ($Cat as $key => $value) {
            $input .= "object: " . $key . "</br>";
        }
        return $input;
    }
}

$name = "meow";
$age = "12";
$string = "'test', 'sample', 'help'";
$Cat = array($name, $age);
$output = Cat::ToData($Cat);
echo $output;
```

This is the best thing that I can come up with
here is the problem, they said I just used an array and not an object.
I used array because I have to put the values on the $Cat so it can be passed on the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set those values to the object here is what you do

```
...
foreach ($Cat as $key => $value) {
    $this->$key = $value;
}
...

$name = "meow";
$age = "12";
$Cat = array("name"=>$name,"age"=> $age);

$cat = new Cat();
$cat->toData($Cat);

echo $cat->name;
// meow
```

**Update**:

Now i get a better idea what you are trying to do, this is how your class will look like:

```
class Cat{
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $string;

    static public function ToData($Cat) {
        $obj = new self();
        $obj->name = $Cat["name"];
        $obj->age  = $Cate["age"];
        $obj->string  = $Cate["string"];
        return $obj;
    }

    // echo 
    public function __toString(){
       return "$this->name - $this->age - $this->string";
    }
}
```

now you can set your values

$name = "meow";
$age = "12";
$string = "'test', 'sample', 'help'";
$Cat = array($name, $age,$string);
$output = Cat::ToData($Cat);
echo $output;

Note that `$output` is an object

Comment: yes but it's on array. I want it in an object with its properties.

Comment: yes thanks. Also can you check my update also. This what my difficult problem is. string ="'test', 'sample', 'help'". I want also to output that with different property. string1, string2, string3.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an assignment on object-oriented programming concept in PHP. I believe this is what you're trying to accomplish, with comments explaining the steps.

```
class Cat{
    public $name;
    public $age;

    // Output the attributes of Cat in a string
    public function ToData() {
        $input = "";
        $input .= "object: name :".": ".$this->name." </br>";
        $input .= "object: age :".": ".$this->age." </br>";
        return $input;
    }
}

$name = "meow";
$age = "12";

// Instantiate Cat
$Cat = new Cat();
$Cat->name = $name;
$Cat->age = $age;

// Output Cat's attributes
$output = $Cat->ToData();
echo $output;
```

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Can you also check my update. Because I want to output that with different properties. string1, string2, string3. string ="'test', 'sample', 'help'".

Comment: You should be able to use the example I gave you to add in `$string` yourself. It's the same as `$name` and `$age`. At least do your own homework a bit. :)

Comment: haha I really get that. Maybe I should put here the whole thing and my problem. I'm just afraid that someone will caught me using stackoverflow. :) I'm so desperate right now. I'll update the code above.